# Is there any way to implement server-side caching using Apollo-server 2.x?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

> Currently I am using "GrandStack" for my application . The challenge I
>   am facing with cache .I want to maintain Cache at both side Client and
>   Back-end.

**At Client:**

I am using React Js, Apollo-client: By default Apollo-client maintain a store at application level (wrap whole application with client using Apollo provide)

> Que here .. If I navigate to any visited page that data should server
>   from cache even on page refresh

**At Backend:**
  I am using Apollo-server 2 + express + Neo4j as DB

> Is there any way to cache "client request" at server ? If user hit same
>   request to server that data should comes from server cache ?

Please help me provide some reference code .Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For same scenario i have implemented LRU cache in which I stored query as a key and response as value.

```
const LRU = require("lru-cache")

const lruCache = new LRU({
    maxElements: 1000,
    length: (n, key) => {
        return n * 2 + key.length
    },
    dispose: function (key, n) {
        // n.close()
    },
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60
})
```

To set value `lruCache.set(key, value)` and to get `const data = lruCache.get(key);`

"key" is your request.

There are other options also but this is most popular(thats what i believe)

URL - https://www.npmjs.com/package/lru-cache

Comment: also refer this https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/tree/master/packages/apollo-server-cache-redis if you want to implement using radis

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, But I am looking only with Apollo, Apollo + radis is the one solution.

Comment: @AnuragGautam, Internally Apollo has support for Radis only (as far as I know). Its all about how you want to implement cache.